# Keil arm Cortex - Find middle number of 3

Tags: assembly, keil, cortex-m

Lets say that i load 3 number values to three different registers. And i want to find the middle number.

```
AREA median, CODE, READONLY
    EXPORT main
first  EQU 3
middle EQU 3
last   EQU 9
    ENTRY

main 
     MOV R0, #first
     MOV R1, #middle
     MOV R2, #last
----------
Here i would like to compare these 3 values and find the middle number. (in this case, 3)
```

I tried something like `CMP R1, R2` but i was not able to store the value that i wanted in a register. This is what i tried to find the smaller or bigger of two.

```
main:
        mov     r1, #3     /* setting up initial variable a */
        mov     r2, #9     /* setting up initial variable b */
        cmp     r1, r2     /* comparing variables to determine which is bigger */
        blt     r1_lower   /* jump to r1_lower in case r2 is bigger  */
        mov     r0, r1     /* if branching/jumping did not occur, r1 is bigger (or the same) so store r1 into r0 */
        b       end        /* proceed to the end */
r1_lower:
        mov r0, r2         /* end up here because r1 was smaller than r2, so move r2 into r0 */
        b end              /* proceed to the end */
```

Any thoughts ?

Comment: What is the initial value of `r0`?

Comment: @fuz The initial value of r0  is 0x00

Comment: For the algorithm, I think you need 3 compares.  It only takes 2 to get min or max, but you can't rule out either value as a possible middle after the first compare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For three numbers specifically, there are two basic approaches:

- you can sort the three numbers and return the middle number from the sorted array.  For this, a three-stage sorting network is generally useful.  To build this, use this primitive which swaps `r0` and `r1` if `r0` is larger than `r1`, using `r3` as a temporary register:

  ```
  cmp   r0, r1     # if (r0 > r1)
  movgt r3, r1     #         r2 = r1
  movgt r1, r0     #         r1 = r0
  movgt r0, r3     #         r0 = r1
  ```
- alternatively, you can compute the maximum and minimum of the three numbers and subtract it from their sum, yielding the number in the middle.  For example, if the three numbers are in `r0`, `r1`, and `r2`, this can be done by:

  ```
  cmp       r0, r1 # if (r0 > r1)
  movgt r3, r0     # then r3 = r0  (r3 is max)
  movgt r4, r1     # then r4 = r1  (r4 is min)
  movle r3, r1     # else r3 = r1
  movle r4, r0     # else r4 = r0
  cmp       r2, r3 # if (r2 > r3)
  movgt r3, r2     # then r3 = r2
  cmp       r4, r2 # if (r4 > r2)
  movgt r4, r2     # then r4 = r2
  add   r5, r0, r1 # r5 = r0 + r1  (r5 is middle)
  add   r5, r5, r2 # r5 = r5 + r2
  sub   r5, r5, r3 # r5 = r5 - r3
  sub   r5, r5, r4 # r5 = r5 - r5
  ```

Answer (score 0):

What was the exact problem you encountered?  Your `CMP` instruction is fine, and will set the status flags depending on the relative values of `R0` and `R1`, so you can then use a conditional branch (e.g. `BHI` or `BGT`) or one of the `IT` family of instructions that will allow you to execute other instructions conditionally using the same condition codes.

There's a quick reference for the Thumb-2 instruction set (as used by most of the Cortex-M devices, which I'll assume you're using in the absence of any other information) [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.qrc0001m/QRC0001_UAL.pdf), and there's plenty more documentation on conditional branching and conditional execution on the ARM Infocenter site, for example [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/CIHDFHCC.html) for the Cortex-M3.